# DNN Regression for multiple inputs

Tags: neural-network, regression

I am trying to use DNN Multivariate Regression to estimate an output that takes 2 features as input. The following is my code (note that the data is clean, and absolutely no NaN exists).

```
 train_set, test_set = train_test_split(Ha_Noi, test_size=0.2, random_state = random.randint(20, 200))

# Training Data
train_X =  np.array(train_set['longwait_percent2'])
train_X2 = np.array(train_set['accept_rate_timeT'])
train_Y =  np.array(train_set['accept_rate'])
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]

#Testing Data
Xtest = np.array(test_set['longwait_percent2'])
Xtest2 = np.array(test_set['accept_rate_timeT'])
Ytest = np.array(test_set['accept_rate'])

#Deep Neural Network Regressor 
feature_column1 = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(train_X)
feature_column2 = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(train_X2)
regressor = learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=[feature_column1, feature_column2], hidden_units=[20, 10])
regressor.fit(x = [feature_column1, feature_column2],y = train_Y, steps= STEPS, batch_size= BATCH_SIZE)
```

When I execute this code, it keeps giving me the error message: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'". I also noticed that the code works perfectly if my x-variable is **1D**-array, rather than 2D. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: No one here could help me with this??